# Test if file exist

Tags: c++, file

```
bool isFileExist(const std::string& fileName)
{
    return !!std::ifstream(fileName.c_str());
}
```

This is a function to check if a file exist. Are there non-obvious problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not testing whether the file exists.  You're actually testing whether you are able to open it for reading.  On POSIX (and POSIX-like) systems, use `stat()`.  For a cross-platform solution, see [this Stack Overflow question](//stackoverflow.com/q/268023/1157100).

Answer (score 1):

I have always hated the `!!` trick. It is so unreadable and you only really know what it is doing once you have tried it a few times.

Also in this case it is totally unnecessary. When a stream is used in a boolean context it is automatically converted to bool (by the same method that the first `!` operator uses). So the code works just as well written like this:

```
bool isFileExist(const std::string& fileName)
{
    return std::ifstream(fileName.c_str());
}
```

Since C++11 (and it is now 2016 (so that is 5 years ago) and we are on the verge of releasing C++17) the ifstream can also take a string for the file name. So we can update the function again.

```
bool isFileExist(const std::string& fileName)
{
    return std::ifstream(fileName);
}
```

Also this test if the file is openable for reading (not if it exists). So you may want to use a more appropriate function.

Comment: My msvc2015.2 gives `Error C2440 'return': cannot convert from 'std::basic_ifstream<char,std::char_traits<char>>' to 'bool'` without `!!`.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: Of course you can, there is also method `is_open()`

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: Then your compiler is broken. **BUT** there are several better solutions than `!!`

Comment: AFAIK `operator bool()` exists in `c++11`, so for `с++03` you still need to use `!!` (`not` + `std::ios::operator!`).

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: `is_open()` or `!fail()` is better there is no need to use dirty tricks like `!!`. Also pre C++11 there is `operator void*()` which can be used in bool context to convert to a boolean value.